# Why does one setter need a TargetName but the other doesn't?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was messing around with styles and setters because I wanted to learn out to create a custom listbox selected style.

Here's what I have

```
     <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" 
         TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="66" />           
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>

                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb" >
                            <ContentPresenter Name="listItemContent" 
                              Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              Width="300" 
                              Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        </TextBlock>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="tb" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>                            
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This works very nicely. However, you will notice that in the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` section, there is a trigger for `IsSelected=True` and `IsSelected=False`

Within these two triggers there are two setters. One for the `ForeGround` and one for the `Background`.

My question is, why does only the background setter need a `TargetName`? Why doesn't both need it? Why does it need it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I realise that there are two correct answers for this question already, I did not feel that they were up to the usual high standard found in Stack Overflow. As such, I have provided the same correct answer, but with more references and information.

If you look on the [`Control.Foreground` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, you will see a section named *Dependency Property Information*. In that section, you will see this:

[image]

Notice that the [`FrameworkPropertyMetadata.Inherits` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.inherits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is displayed. From the linked page, this *Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the value of the dependency property is inheritable*. Therefore, we learn that the `Control.Foreground DependencyProperty` value will be inherited by child controls.

Now, if you look on the [`Control.Background` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN at the *Dependency Property Information* section, you will see this:

[image]

You will have noticed that the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata.Inherits` Property is missing from this page. That means that the `Control.Background` Property value is *not* inherited by child controls.

So the reason why you didn't need to specify the [`Setter.TargetName` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.targetname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value for the `Foreground` Property is because without specifying a target for it, the value will actually be applied on the whole `ListBoxItem` and then that value will be inherited by all child controls within the `ListBoxItem`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because the Foreground property is inherited, whereas Background property is not.  See the following: [Property Value Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a target name, the setter will apply its modification to the element targeted by the ControlTemplate (the ListBoxItem). The Foreground property is inherited by default in WPF so it will be applied to your TextBlock too.

If you don't want to specify a targetname for your Background, you can use the TemplateBinding, it will bind your background to the background of your ListBoxItem :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <TextBlock Background={TemplateBinding Background}>
        <ContentPresenter Name="listItemContent" 
          Grid.RowSpan="2" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Width="300" 
          Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    </TextBlock>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>                            
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```